# how can I preserve this json format, while adding to it before serializing it?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a fairly complex json file I am deserializing into a datatable to be displayed to datgridview.

when it comes in the json file has alot of values and properties in it.

i add about 5-6 properties to it myself for manipulation in my software. When I am all done with my software here I want to serialize this datatable back to json. but with the added properties.

problem is I finally figured out how to serialize my properties back to the file, and realized that in the process I dont serialize all the other fields back in it seems. there are dozens of them and they are nested. I'm not to sure how to get all the nested info into a datatable.

can anyone explain or help me pack all this info into my datatable?
below will be some code snips to show my process so far.

***Here is main event***

this is where I deserialize the file and load to datagridview.

```
public void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var loadscreen = new SplashScreen();
        loadscreen.Show();

        //double buffer fixes latency when scrolling thru datagridviews
        toolDataGridView.GetType().GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | 
        BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(toolDataGridView, true, 
        null);

        //json file holding all data to be parsed for tool list.
        string myDynamicJSON = File.ReadAllText(@"testLibrary.json");

        //object with json data in it
        ToolJson ToolData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ToolJson>(myDynamicJSON);

        //DataTable with something in it, do the binding
        BindingSource SBind = new BindingSource
        { 
            DataSource = tooldataSet.Tables["Tool"]
        };

        //looks into File finds json fields, and assign them to variables to be used in C# to 
        create the rows.
        foreach (var datum in ToolData.datum)
        {
            string description = datum.Description;
            string vendor = datum.Vendor;
            double cost = datum.Cost;
            string serial = datum.ProductLink;
            string employee = datum.employee;
            string location = datum.location;
            bool returntool = datum.returnTool;
            int onHand = datum.onHandQty;
            int stockQty = datum.stockQty;
            int orderQty = ToolData.Order(datum.stockQty, datum.onHandQty); //stockQty - 
            onHand = orderQty, if value is less than 0, set the value of orderQty to 0.
            string toolType = datum.Type;
            double diameter = datum.Geometry.Dc;
            double OAL = datum.Geometry.Oal;
            string productID = datum.ProductId;

            //Populate the DataTable with rows of data
            DataRow dr = tooldataSet.Tool.NewRow();

            // Fill the values
            dr["Description"] = description;
            dr["Vendor"] = vendor;
            dr["Cost"] = cost;
            dr["Serial #"] = serial;
            dr["Employee"] = employee;
            dr["Location"] = location;
            dr["OnHand"] = onHand;
            dr["StockQty"] = stockQty;
            dr["OrderQty"] = orderQty;
            dr["Return"] = returntool;
            dr["Diameter"] = diameter;
            dr["OAL"] = OAL;
            dr["Type"] = toolType;
            dr["Product Id"] = productID;

            //once all data is added to the row, add the row, and loop untill all data is 
            loaded.
            tooldataSet.Tool.Rows.Add(dr);

        }

        toolDataGridView.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = 
        DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing;
        toolDataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;

        //bind our dataset.table to the gridview
        toolDataGridView.DataSource = SBind;

        toolDataGridView.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = 
        DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.EnableResizing;
        toolDataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = true;
        //fills drop down employee list with names from the text file
        PopulateList(@"EmployeeList.txt");

        //hide splashscreen once Gridview has loaded the data
        loadscreen.Hide();

    }
```

***Here is simple button click event to trigger the serializing back to the file***

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource SBind = new BindingSource
        {
            DataSource = tooldataSet.Tables["Tool"]
        };
        toolDataGridView.DataSource = SBind;

        var serialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tooldataSet.Tool, 
        Formatting.Indented);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"testLibrary.json", serialized);
    }
```

***And finally here is a snippet of the json file, this is only 1 item in the list of hundreds***

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "BMC": "carbide",
        "Cost": 52.68,
        "Employee": "",
        "GRADE": "Mill Generic",
        "Location": "",
        "description": "5/8-11\"",
        "geometry": {
            "CSP": false,
            "DC": 0.433,
            "HAND": true,
            "LB": 2,
            "LCF": 0.5,
            "NOF": 4,
            "NT": 1,
            "OAL": 5,
            "SFDM": 0.625,
            "TP": 0.0909091,
            "shoulder-length": 1.969,
            "thread-profile-angle": 60
        },
        "guid": "0112c196-8a79-421d-8dda-d4aa964aa6d7",
        "holder": {
            "description": "Maritool CAT40-ER32-2.35",
            "guid": "e800051b-e2d6-4699-a2b6-dad6466a0a0c",
            "last_modified": 1485790626152,
            "product-id": "CAT40-ER32-2.35",
            "product-link": "",
            "segments": [
                {
                    "height": 0.148,
                    "lower-diameter": 1.5,
                    "upper-diameter": 1.97
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.836,
                    "lower-diameter": 1.97,
                    "upper-diameter": 1.97
                }
                
            ],
            "type": "holder",
            "unit": "inches",
            "vendor": "Maritool"
        },
        "onHandQty": 3,
        "post-process": {
            "break-control": false,
            "comment": "",
            "diameter-offset": 17,
            "length-offset": 17,
            "live": true,
            "manual-tool-change": false,
            "number": 17,
            "turret": 0
        },
        "product-id": "GMDTTM58-11UN4FL",
        "product-link": "6010",
        "start-values": {
            "presets": [
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "f_n": 0.012091641057817,
                    "f_z": 0.0031,
                    "guid": "b118ce46-da35-4ed6-9806-b98e05ffe077",
                    "n": 2646.45632854884,
                    "n_ramp": 2646,
                    "name": "Tool Steel",
                    "tool-coolant": "flood",
                    "use-stepdown": false,
                    "use-stepover": false,
                    "v_c": 300,
                    "v_f": 32.8160584740056,
                    "v_f_leadIn": 32,
                    "v_f_leadOut": 32,
                    "v_f_plunge": 32,
                    "v_f_ramp": 32
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "f_n": 0.01118476797848,
                    "f_z": 0.0028,
                    "guid": "0e1767f5-b0ef-422f-b49d-6cb8c3eb06ed",
                    "n": 3308.0704106860494,
                    "n_ramp": 3308,
                    "name": "Stainless Steel",
                    "tool-coolant": "flood",
                    "use-stepdown": false,
                    "use-stepover": false,
                    "v_c": 375,
                    "v_f": 37.0503885996837,
                    "v_f_leadIn": 37,
                    "v_f_leadOut": 37,
                    "v_f_plunge": 37,
                    "v_f_ramp": 37
                }
            ]
        },
        "stockQty": 5,
        "type": "thread mill",
        "unit": "inches",
        "vendor": "Gorilla Mill"
    }
]
 }
```

***EDIT***

Figured I should add in what my result is right now if I click m button

```
    [
    {
    "Description": "5/8-11\"",
"Cost": 0.0,
"Vendor Item Number": null,
"Vendor Item": null,
"Serial #": "6010",
"Source": null,
"Description3": null,
"Description2": null,
"LastInventory": null,
"Last Price": null,
"DC": "0.433",
"OAL": "5",
"GUID": "0112c196-8a79-421d-8dda-d4aa964aa6d7",
"Product Id": null,
"Type": "thread mill",
"OnHandQty": 0,
"StockQty": 0,
"OrderQty": 0,
"Return": false,
"Employee": "",
"Vendor": "Gorilla Mill",
"Location": "",
"Grade": "Mill Generic",
"BMC": "Carbide",
"start-values": "QuickType.StartValues",
"unit": "Inches",
"geometry": "QuickType.Geometry",
"CSP": "False",
"HAND": "True",
"LB": "2",
"LCF": "0.5",
"NOF": "4",
"NT": "1",
"SFDM": "0.625",
"TP": "0",
"shoulder-length": "1.969",
"thread-profile-angle": "60",
"SIG": "0",
"RE": "0",
"TA": "0",
"tip-diameter": "0",
"tip-length": "0",
"break-control": "False",
"comment": "",
"diameter offset": "17",
"length offset": "17",
"live": "True",
"manual tool change": "False",
"number": "17",
"turret": "0",
"presets": "QuickType.Preset[]",
"holder": "QuickType.Holder",
"post-process": "QuickType.PostProcess",
"Diameter": null,
"last_modified": null,
"product-id": "GMDTTM58-11UN4FL",
"product-link": null,
"segments": null
    }
    ]
```

Also to note I got my class using quicktype.io online, so the class can handle the entire file no problem(I would assume)

***EDIT AGAIN***

```
namespace QuickType
 {
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;


public class ToolJson
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<Datum> datum { get; set; }
    

    [JsonProperty("version")]
    public long Version { get; set; }

    public int Order(int stockQty, int onHandQty)
    {

        int orderQty = stockQty - onHandQty;
        if (orderQty < 0)
        {
            orderQty = 0;
        }
        return orderQty;

    }
}

public partial class Datum
{
    [JsonProperty("BMC")]
    public Bmc Bmc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("GRADE")]
    public string Grade { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("geometry")]
    public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("guid")]
    public string Guid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("holder")]
    public Holder holder { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("post-process")]
    public PostProcess PostProcess { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product-id")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product-link")]
    public string ProductLink { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("start-values")]
    public StartValues StartValues { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("unit")]
    public Unit Unit { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vendor")]
    public string Vendor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Cost")]
    public double Cost { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Employee")]
    public string employee { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Location")]
    public string location { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("onHandQty")]
    public int onHandQty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("stockQty")]
    public int stockQty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("orderQty")]
    public int orderQty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ReturnTool")]
    public bool returnTool { get; set; }

}

public partial class Geometry
{
    [JsonProperty("CSP")]
    public bool Csp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DC")]
    public double Dc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("HAND")]
    public bool Hand { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LB")]
    public double Lb { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LCF")]
    public double Lcf { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("NOF")]
    public long Nof { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("NT")]
    public long Nt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OAL")]
    public double Oal { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SFDM")]
    public double Sfdm { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TP")]
    public double Tp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("shoulder-length")]
    public double ShoulderLength { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("thread-profile-angle")]
    public long ThreadProfileAngle { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SIG")]
    public long Sig { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("RE")]
    public double Re { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TA")]
    public long Ta { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tip-diameter")]
   public double TipDiameter { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tip-length")]
    public double TipLength { get; set; }
}

public partial class Holder
{
    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("guid")]
    public string Guid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_modified")]
    public string LastModified { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product-id")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product-link")]
    public string ProductLink { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("segments")]
    public Segment[] Segments { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("unit")]
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vendor")]
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
}

public partial class Segment
{
    [JsonProperty("height")]
    public double Height { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lower-diameter")]
    public double LowerDiameter { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("upper-diameter")]
    public double UpperDiameter { get; set; }
}

public partial class PostProcess
{
    [JsonProperty("break-control")]
    public bool BreakControl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("comment")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("diameter-offset")]
    public long DiameterOffset { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("length-offset")]
    public long LengthOffset { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("live")]
    public bool Live { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("manual-tool-change")]
    public bool ManualToolChange { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("number")]
    public long Number { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("turret")]
    public long Turret { get; set; }
}

public partial class StartValues
{
    [JsonProperty("presets")]
    public Preset[] Presets { get; set; }
}

public partial class Preset
{
    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("f_n")]
    public double? FN { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("f_z")]
    public double? FZ { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("guid")]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("n")]
    public double N { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("n_ramp")]
    public double? NRamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tool-coolant")]
    public ToolCoolant ToolCoolant { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("use-stepdown")]
    public bool UseStepdown { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("use-stepover")]
    public bool UseStepover { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("v_c")]
    public double VC { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("v_f")]
    public double? VF { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("v_f_leadIn")]
    public double? VFLeadIn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("v_f_leadOut")]
    public double VFLeadOut { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("v_f_plunge")]
    public double VFPlunge { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("v_f_ramp")]
    public double VFRamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("v_f_retract")]
    public double VFRetract { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("stepdown")]
    public double Stepdown { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("stepover")]
    public double Stepover { get; set; }
}

public enum Bmc { Carbide, Hss };

public enum Grade { Generic, MillGeneric };

public enum Description { LongHolder, MaritoolCat40Er32235 };

public enum ProductId { Cat40Er32235, Empty };

public enum TypeEnum { Holder };

public enum Unit { Inches, Millimeters };

public enum Vendor { Empty, Maritool };

public enum ToolCoolant { Disabled, Flood };
```

***Latest Edit***
the following code will deser and then set the object to the DGV. other than this small bit of code there isn't much else I have to load the content.

```
var v = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ToolJson> 
(File.ReadAllText(@"testLibrary.json"));

        //set DGV source to our datums 
        toolDataGridView.DataSource = v.Datums.Cast<IInteresting> 
        ().ToList();
```

***Newest Edit***

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Newtonsoft;
 using Newtonsoft.Json;

 namespace QuickType
{
public interface IInteresting
{
    //adding below creates the columns for our DGV
    string ProductLink {get;set;}
    string Type { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    string Vendor { get; set; }
    double GeometryDc { get; set; }
    double GeometryOal { get; set; }
    double Cost { get; set; }
    int onHandQty { get; set; }
    int OrderQty { get; set; }
    int stockQty { get; set; }
    string location { get; set; }
    string employee { get; set; }
}
public partial class Datum : IInteresting
{
    //top level props in datum
    public int OrderQty { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("product-link")]
    public string ProductLink { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Cost")]
    public double Cost { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Employee")]
    public string employee { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Location")]
    public string location { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("onHandQty")]
    public int onHandQty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("stockQty")]
    public int stockQty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("orderQty")]
    public int orderQty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ReturnTool")]
    public bool returnTool { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vendor")]
    public string Vendor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product-id")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }


    //below are the props that are nested, we need to pull them out of 
    the nest
    [JsonIgnore]
    public double GeometryDc
    {
        get => this.Geometry.Dc;
        set => this.Geometry.Dc = value;
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public double GeometryOal
    {
        get => this.Geometry.Oal;
        set => this.Geometry.Oal = value;
    }
}
 }
```

***Edit including Serialization***
the button click event below, should simulate what should happen when the user closes the form. button click instead for testing.
what happens is it serializes, but its not in the correct format.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\User\OneDrive - Motion 
                    Controls Robotics, Inc\Desktop\test 
                    inventory\testLibrary1.json", 
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toolDataGridView.DataSource, 
                    Formatting.Indented));
    }
```

Comment: something like this? Bmc bmc = datum.Bmc;
                double cost = datum.Cost;
                string employee = datum.employee;
                String grade = datum.Grade;
                string location = datum.location;
                string description = datum.Description;
                Geometry geometry = datum.Geometry;
                    //subs of geometry
                    bool csp = datum.Geometry.Csp;
                    double diameter = datum.Geometry.Dc;
                    bool hand = datum.Geometry.Hand;
                  etc..?

Comment: pretty much in my foreach loop assign every single property to a variable and put them all in the datatable? then just only show what i need?

Comment: Have you got your actual classes available to post into the question?

Comment: yes will add right now

Comment: added the json file to the very end of my question

Comment: did some tinkering and added alot more content to the output. still cant figure out how to handle the nested properties though.

Answer (score 1):

Add this somewhere, in another class:

```
    public interface IInteresting
    {
        string Description { get; set; }
        double GeometryDc { get; set; }
        double GeometryOal { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class Datum : IInteresting
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public double GeometryDc { 
            get => this.Geometry.Dc; 
            set => this.Geometry.Dc = value;
        }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public double GeometryOal
        {
            get => this.Geometry.Oal;
            set => this.Geometry.Oal = value;
        }
    }
```

This is just a fragment; you can fill in the other props later. I have deomnstrated an interface that has 3 props. One is a straight up a property of Datum already (Description). The other two are props that dig out nested data; they need implementing, like I showed, including the `JsonIgnore` tag. Your remaining props are likely to be similar to either the first case (already a prop of Datum, just needs mentioning in interface) or a nested data (needs a new name inventing in interface and a new code putting to dig it out of the hierarchy)

Then put this code behind in a new form called Form1 that contain a DataGridView1 and a Button1 (in the designer):

```
    public Form1(string s1 = null)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var v = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ToolJson>(File.ReadAllText("textfile1.json"));

        //note I renamed your `datum` property to `Datums`
        dataGridView1.DataSource = v.Datums.Cast<IInteresting>().ToList();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataGridView1.DataSource);

    } //put a breakpoint on this line
```

The datagridview gets a list of `IInteresting`, and it only makes columns for props on an `IInteresting`, so in this case I see 3 columns (3 props):

[image]

Edit some data

[image]

Click the button. The datasource of the grid (it contains all the data, not just the visible ones) is serialized and the output contains all the data

[image]

---

#### Adding new data, not already present in the json:

```
public interface IInteresting
{
    string Description { get; set; }
    double GeometryDc { get; set; }
    double GeometryOal { get; set; }

    string DatumXxNew {get; set;}
    string GeometryXxNew {get; set;}
}

public partial class Datum : IInteresting
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public double GeometryDc { 
        get => this.Geometry.Dc; 
        set => this.Geometry.Dc = value;
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public double GeometryOal
    {
        get => this.Geometry.Oal;
        set => this.Geometry.Oal = value;
    }

    //do not JsonIgnore
    public string DatumXxNew {get; set;}

    //DO JsonIgnore this one, but NOT the one it links to
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string GeometryXxNew {
      get => this.Geometry.XxNew; 
      set => this.Geometry.XxNew = value; 
    }
}

public partial class Geometry{

    //do not JsonIgnore
    public string XxNew {get;set;} 
}
```

Comment: interesting, i have never tried using an interface yet. only read about them. I will give this a go. i have my software in shambles right now screwing with this so hoping i can get it patched back together after all this!

Comment: the first bit that makes the interface up gives me 9 errors. cant find def for Geometry. going to keep going to see if it fixes itself when i do the other part

Comment: Probably because the "somewhere" you put the interface is not inside the QuickType namespace, nor does the file have `using QuickType` at the top

Comment: I forgot to say "if you have new properties you want to *add* to the json output then you should a) put them in the interface, b) put them in the Datum (if they are like Description) or a sub level object and put a top level property for them (if they are like Geometry.Dc) and c) do NOT put JsonIgnore on them, because you DO want to serialize them (but DO JsonIgnore any GeometryDc style top level "digger" properties)

Comment: does the [JsonIgnore] just skip those properties when serializing? I still need those properties to show up on the re serialized file. pretty am just adding a few properties like a stock quantity.

Comment: JsonIgnore prevents the property it is used on from serializing. You don't want to serialize e.g. GeometryDc (the "digging" property that brings Geometry.Dc up to Datum level so a datagridview can see it) but you do want to serialize the Dc property inside the Geometry property, if that makes sense

Comment: Added some advisory code on putting new props

Comment: VS doesn't like when I add [JsonIgnore]. but i think what you are saying is, that the jsonignore will ignore the top level. but when we make the sub levels we want to serialize those. correct?

Comment: I mean if you look through the class i have where datum is at, there is a partial class already for geometry, holder, etc. can i not just make the geometry field in datum into a list, and then the geometry class can be the pieces of the list? loop thru this for each item?

Comment: You need to add a using for Newtonsoft.Json to be able to add a jsonignore attribute

Comment: yea i have that already. i figured that much out with some googling. i dont think i am using a new enough version of C# or something

Comment: I think what i am trying to do is make another foreach inside my foreach for datum. the new one would be for geometry. i turned geometry into a list on my class.

Comment: *can i not just make the geometry field in datum into a list* - no, because the json isn't shaped like that and de/ser will stop working if you do

Comment: *and then the geometry class can be the pieces of the list* - it doesn't quite make sense to me; a list is a piece of a class, not the other way round

Comment: at the very top of ToolJson class there is a list called datum, so I'm not understanding why, inside that list i can't have a list called Geometry that holds all my data from the partial class Geometry, just like the partial class Datum. that is exactly how it is structured in the json.(Again I'm just making educated guesses) But with the interface, it gave me errors i couldnt get around.

Comment: *the jsonignore will ignore the top level. but when we make the sub levels we want to serialize those. correct?* - the only top level properties you want to ignore are "digging" ones that retrieve data from deeper levels of the hierarchy. DataGridView will only ever show data from the top level. JSON will always represent data that has many levels. Hence if we want to show data that is not at the top level, in the grid, then we must retrieve it from the deeper level but we don't want the property that digs it out, to end up in the json, so we jsonignore any top level properties that dig

Comment: *list called datum* - which should be called "Datums" because a) properties in c# should be in PascalCase but more importantly, b) it is a List of Datum objects so it should have a plural name to outline that it is multiple Datum

Comment: *inside that list i can't have a list called Geometry* - I think you're using the word "list" incorrectly here. You have a List of Datum but you don't add anything to the **List** you add it to the **Datum**.. but a Datum already has a Geometry **property**, which is a single instance (not a list) of a **class** called Geometry

Comment: i dont need to display any of the sub levels to the datagridview. just maintain their integrity so when i reserialize the file they are still there and in the correct format. i will change the datum to Datums to be politically correct. it is something that has made sense to me but didnt want to take the time to do it.

Comment: *which is a single instance (not a list) of a class called Geometry* can i not make this is a list? it is structured in the json identical to the datum

Comment: Clicking on `datum` and pressing Ctrl-R-R will enter rename mode, which will rename it everywhere. It's not something that "takes time"

Comment: neat feature didn't know about that. thanks.

Comment: *i dont need to display any of the sub levels to the datagridview* - your original code, for example, digs out OAL from inside of the sub object Geometry and puts into a dataset, which is then wired to a grid; this is why I assumed you wanted to show sub level properties in the grid

Comment: If you never want to show any sub level property in the grid, just do a grid.DataSource = ToolDats.Datums; - all the rest of this stuff with the dataset can disappear

Comment: wouldnt it be datasource = Tool which is the datatable where all my rows are being populated? not sure why datasource would be tooldata.datums.

Comment: Because you've said you only want to edit naturally top level properties of a Datum, and `ToolJson.Datums` (renamed from `datum`, note `ToolJson` should really be called `toolJson` because it is a local variable, which are camelCase..) is a List of Datum - `List<Datum>`, and is therefore suitable for binding to a grid's DataSource. There is no need for a datatable at all

Comment: interesting. ill give it a go. sorry this got so drawn out. Once again i appreciate the help Caius! ill change toolJson to camelCase as well.

Comment: after some more tinkering i went back to the interface and got that to work. will see how it goes trying it that way.

Comment: Yep, the interface is just a way to limit the number of columns that appear in the grid. Alternative ways are to remove columns after you set the DataSource (if auto generate is on) or add them manually (and turn off auto generate)

Comment: In essence, the way to resolve this query fastest would be to tell me exactly which of the known json properties should appear in the grid, and if there are any new properties to be added to the output json that are not in the input json

Comment: got all m columns in place. reduced my code by about 100 lines. Still not sure how your example is working for you though. when i click my button to serialize it doesnt do anything. i made a messagebox after to display x and it just freezes up for a second or 2 and then carries on.

Comment: product-link, type, description,vendor,geometryDc, geometryOal, then added ones, location,employee,stockQty,onHandQty, and orderQty. i can get them all to dgv but my values i type in DGV should save and be there when i reopen the softare

Comment: The geometryDc and OAL ones are not top level on the source json, they're sub level (datum.Geometry.Dc) - how does this align with your earlier comment that you don't need any sub level ones (above, *i dont need to display any of the sub levels to the datagridview* )

Comment: i dont need them. they can go away. but if i can use them that is better. but again not needed.

Comment: Can you show the code you've written in order to "get them into the grid"? (as an edit to the question)

Comment: added at end of my initial question. its like 2 lines. you might of even helped me with that specific code actually.

Comment: Have you got the code for the `partial class Datum:IInteresting` available too? (The Datum in the Q is the partial that just deals with the json, not the implementation of the IInteresting)

Comment: pretty much identical to your example. added a few extra props as i was working on it the other day. newest edit added

Comment: Looks reasonable.. Propery names have gone a bit wonky but nothing that should cause a problem.. So you're saying the deser is taking too long? Have you got that latest code too?

Comment: alright. realized i never seriaized to a file. just serialized to a variable. so that is kinda fixed. but the format is still off. doesnt look like the original format. the whole thing needs to perfectly match the original format.

Comment: the whole thing needs enclosed in a top level data [], and my bmc properties and unit property arent returning the proper values. i can figure out the properties i think. but not sure how to encapsulate the entire thing in another level.

Comment: You need to serialize a ToolJson containing a List, not a List. So something like `var serializeMe = new ToolJson{ Datums = DataGridView.DataSource as List<Datum> }`

Comment: this leaves me with a empty file. well close enough. {
  "data": null,
  "version": 0
}

Comment: i understand the issue being that it is indeed serializing the top level like it is supposed to. its just not creating the list. presumably because it doesnt see my Datums as data?

Comment: Oh.. yes that cast won't work. try `var serializeMe = new ToolJson{ Datums = (DataGridView.DataSource as List<IInteresting>).Cast<Datum>().ToList();` or, if youre not adding items to the grid (only adding data to existing items) you could keep the original deser'd ToolJson somewhere (class level varaible) with its Datums, and ser that

Comment: that worked. thank you so much for the help. its so amazing how efficient code can get. at the start of this question my code was significantly longer than it is now. I'm slowly learning. its a painful process. but I'm glad you stuck thru this and helped me all the way thru. i have to read up on casting. thats a new one for me.

Comment: Yep, in short, when an object like a Datum implements an interface like IIntersting, it means you can treat it as a Datum, or an IInteresting, or some other parent, like object. `Datum d = new Datum; IInteresting i = d; object o = d; Datum retrieved1 = (Datum)i; Datum retrieved2 = (Datum)o;` - all legal.. We took our `List<Datum>` and casted every item so they looked like they were just `IInteresting`s i.e. a `List<IInteresting>` - they're still a `Datum` in reality, but they look like an `IInteresting`.

Comment: To revert, we cast them all from the `IInteresting` they look like, to the `Datum` they really are, but critically (and the thing I forgot about, re what it really was when I made the first cast), a `List<Datum>` and a `List<IInteresting>` are not the same thing; just because we can treat a Datum as an IInteresting, doesn't automatically mean we can treat a `List<Datum>` as a `List<IInteresting>`... However, there are some cases where we can make such equivalences. Look up [co/contra variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Comment: Hah, I would have learnt a lot more if I had any kind of focus. Pretty sure what I know could be learnt in a year, though I've been at this game a lot longer than that..

Comment: Yea. I lack focus, I bought a book on C# that I read thru in my leisure time, but if my 4 kids arent bothering me I still hit a brick wall when it start talking OOP haha. anyways... thank you very much! I'm very thankful for your continued input on my posts here!